# How do you manage multiple #onSubmits for multiple form children components of the same parent in Redux Form?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-form

In Redux-Form, it seems like you pass `onSubmit` as a prop to your form component and then the form component will have a `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` property on its form tag. This makes sense as Redux-Form will then gather up all of your form data and pass it in as one single object parameter to your `onSubmit` function. But what happens when you have multiple form component children of the same parent component? You can only have one `onSubmit` function to pass to both your form children even though they need to do different things with their submitted information. Is the only solution to have multiple parents for multiple forms just so you can pass in a different `onSubmit`? To me this seems not very DRY.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [composition](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html) concept of reactjs here.

What you need to is :-

Keep a common form, lets call it CommonForm.js. This form is going to attached to your redux form. So all your form common functions(maybe opening form,closing form) would be implemented here.

**P.S : No Field components should be present here.**

Now, say you have 5 different forms which you want to render. Lets take the example of first form. I will name the file FirstForm.js.

Here in FirstForm.js you render your fields and pass your rendered fields as props to your CommonForm(I am using composition here).

Check the following code:-

**Form 1**

```
     class Form1 extends Component {
       render(){
        const renderedFields = this.renderFormFields()
        return(
           <CommonForm {...this.props} renderedFields = {renderedFields } />
        )
      } 
     }
```

**CommonForm**

```
class CommonForm extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    const { data,initialize} = this.props
    if(data){
      initialize(data)
    }
  }

  render(){
    const { renderedFormFieldss }  = this.props
    return(
      <div className='form-container'>
        <form onSubmit={this.instrumentSplitCreateOrUpdate()}>
          {renderedFormFields}
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

CommonForm = reduxForm({fields: ["text"], validate : validateInputField})(CommonForm)

export default CommonForm
```

This way you are using same base component to connect to redux form.

**DYNAMIC FORMS:-**

Ideally above should solve your query but there is something more interesting. If you went through the code proper in the last line of common form you can see I am passing following as parameter:-

```
{fields: ["text"]}
```

So, in this you can create forms with variable names.Say you have same forms used by multiple components and you want to render same form but with different names. For this you can try following:-

```
<CommonForm {...this.props} renderedFields = {renderedFields } />
```

While calling CommonForm from say Form1 pass a prop called `form` with the variable name with which you want to create form. You can something like following:-

```
<CommonForm form='//some key' {...this.props} renderedFields = {renderedFields } />
```